# How to remote debug Confluence plugin with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, confluence

I found the [article](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/developer-tools/working-in-an-ide/creating-a-remote-debug-target) and Eclipse remote debug dialog, pictured below, I wonder if the setting for `Host` is also `localhost` if we both install Confluence and Jira?

Usually we use `localhost:1990/confluence` to link to Confluence, but how does the host link to Confluence not Jira since we don't indicate which application we want to link?

[image: The Eclipse remote debug dialog picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume jira and confluence both trigger the eclipse debugger. Isn't that the case?

If you start your applications with atlas-debug you should see this in your logs:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] jvmInputArguments = -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5005,suspend=n,server=y -Xms128m
```

where address specifies the debug port.

Also you should see this

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

You can specify the adress (debug port) yourself see this answer here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/208296/debugging-jira-and-confluence-plug-ins-via-eclipse

Comment: After set the "Host" field to "localhost", and the "Port" to "5005", click the "Debug" button on "Debug Configurations", the debugging mode works!